# Create if/else flag column based on group value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` which looks like this

```
ID timediff group_count 
1  30        1                
2  20        4           
2  25        4           
2  40        4           
2  27        4           
3  15        3           
3  10        3           
3  40        3
```

I'm trying to create a flag column which assess records on a group ID level to check if following conditions are met:

```
if df.timediff =< 30 OR 
(df.timediff >30 and df.count >=4 )     
then df[flag]=1 
else df[flag]=0`
```

`df` should flag like this then

```
ID timediff group_count flag1 
1  30        1           1     
2  20        4           1
2  25        4           1
2  40        4           1
2  27        4           1
3  15        3           0
3  10        3           0
3  40        3           0
```

Groups flagged with 0 should be dropped. Wondering if those 0 can be dropped immediately.

Comment: `df['flag'] = ((df.timediff <= 30) | ((df.timediff > 30) & (df.group_count >= 4))).astype(int)`

Comment: Just index it `df = df[(df.timediff <= 30) | ((df.timediff > 30) & (df.group_count >= 4))]`? Although the initial `group_count` column and the output `group_count` column do not match and it is unclear why.

Comment: Your example is incorrect: `count` versus `group_count`, and you have more flags being `0` in your outcome than your condition would lead to.

Comment: Yes sorry, copy & paste error, input/output columns should be of course identical

Comment: that was truly simple.  probably there is a more elegant way doing (groupby & lambda & filter e.g ) this but for my purpose this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `groupby` `transform` create the conditions

```
cond = df['timediff'].le(30).groupby(df['ID']).transform('all')
cnt = df.groupby('ID')['timediff'].transform('count')
df['new'] = (((cnt>=4) & (~cond)) | cond).astype(int)
df
Out[194]: 
   ID  timediff  group_count  new
0   1        30            1    1
1   2        20            4    1
2   2        25            4    1
3   2        40            4    1
4   2        27            4    1
5   3        15            3    0
6   3        10            3    0
7   3        40            3    0
```